# configuration issue. "Configuration with name 'default' not found"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am relatively new to Android development and VERY new to Android Studio (much more experienced with Eclipse + android plugin). I am trying to edit a github project, but I can't seem to get it to even compile! I have been reading up, and my error seems to have to do with the build.gradle/locations of libraries themselves.

My error is:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

It also says "Gradle project sync failed, but I think its related to the above error…whatever that means.

My outer build.gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And my inner build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wisely.loyalty"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.0"
}
   buildTypes {
       release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':cwac')
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use     this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
}
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

EDIT:
General file hierarchy

```
root
    .idea
    app
       libs
           cwac
           fb
           utils
        src
         … all source files
    gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
External Libraries
    Android API 20 Platform
    JDK
```

EDIT: Settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':facebook', ':cwac', ':utils'
project(':facebook').projectDir = new File('app/libs/facebook')
project(':cwac').projectDir = new File('app/libs/cwac')
project(':utils').projectDir = new File('app/libs/utils')
```

Progress Update:
I've tried moving the library files around in the directory to no avail. I also tried using my eclipse environment which just seemed to have even more issues. I really need to get this project configured properly!

UPDATE #2:
I have a strong feeling that this has to do with the gradle version since the file configuration seems fine, and its likely my computer that is lacking something. I am new to using gradle. Is there a way to update it? Or is it simply updated through the support libraries in the sdk manager?

Comment: show your settings.gradle file

Comment: In general this is a mismatch between what's in your settings.gradle file and how your project is actually laid out on disk. Without including your settings.gradle file there's no way to diagnose it.

Comment: I see. I posted my settings.gradle file, but it seems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your library folder in your root location of your project and copy all the library files there. For ex YourProject/library then sync it

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I posted my file hierarchy above. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: cwac and fb library should be inside your root folder and not inside libs folder and post your settings.gradle file

Comment: settings.gradle seems to be pointing to the correct location. I edited some errors with the hierarchy as well